# How to throw an error in nextjs (server) if the method is GET and supported but no parameter is passed?

Tags: express, routes, next.js

```
export default function handler(req, res {
  const {
    method,
    query: { pid },
  } = req;

  if (method === 'GET') {
    if (pid) {
      res.statusCode = 200;
      res.end(`Post: ${pid}`);
    } else {
      try {
        const error = 'No post id specified';
        throw new Error(error);
      } catch (err) {
        res.statusCode = 400;
        res.end(`error: ${err}`);
      }
    }
  } else {
    const error = `unsupported method ${method}`;
    try {
      throw new Error(error);
    } catch (err) {
      res.statusCode = 400;
      res.end(`error: ${err}`);
    }
  }
}
```

> If the route `/posts/` is called (without specifying `pid`), the above will return the 404 page's HTML but not the intended error "No post id specified"

The unsupported route if-branch works correctly instead.

**How to obtain the above-explained behavior**?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
const Page = ({ error, pid }) => {
  if(error) return <p>{error}</p>
  return <p>The following Page ID was passed {pid}</p>
}


export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const { pid } = context.query;
  
  if(!pid || typeof pid === 'undefined'){
      return { 
          props { error: 'No pid passed' }
      }
  }
  return {
    props: { pid }
  }
}

export default Page;
```

On the server side you can get the passed param from `context.query` the param needs to have the same name as the file in this case `[pid].js`

Then you simply check if the param is null or undefined. If so you return an error to message in the props to the component. Otherwise you return the PID or do a server side fetch and return the data to the component.